# Trying to create an event in phpmyadmin where records older than 5 days are deleted

Tags: sql, web, events, phpmyadmin, scheduler

I was writing a query to delete any row which has a post date over 5 days ago. The postDate format is date('Y-m-d H:i:s').

When debugging I just tried deleting all rows in the table which worked and deleted the entire table every 10 seconds. But when adding the rest of the statement it seems like not working when I use the "getdate()" function.

I made it recur every 10 seconds and compare it to a future date for testing reasons.

```sql
ON SCHEDULE 
EVERY 10 SECOND 
ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE 
DO 
DELETE FROM posts WHERE postDate < DATEADD(dd,1,GETDATE())
```

No records in the table are deleted even if I make it

```sql
DELETE FROM posts WHERE postDate != DATEADD(dd,1,GETDATE())
```

Records only deleted when the statement is:

```sql
DELETE FROM posts
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am not wrong...

This delete will remove everything, due to you are including all the posts created before than tomorrow, so I think that means all the posts.

```
DELETE FROM posts WHERE postDate < DATEADD(dd,1,GETDATE())
```

This delete will remove all the records whose postDate will be different than tomorrow, so I reach the same conclusion than the previous point.

```
DELETE FROM posts WHERE postDate != DATEADD(dd,1,GETDATE())
```

This delete deletes the whole table

```
DELETE FROM posts
```

I recommend you to change your DATEADD by this to match with your requirements ("to delete any row which has a post date over 5 days ago"):

```
DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL -5 day)
```

Comment: Thanks, but the query doesn't work whenever I use DATEADD. Even if I do 

```sql
WHERE postDate != DATEADD(dd, -5,GETDATE())
```

Comment: Yes, that's because you are using mysql. You must adapt that function to the `DATEADD` function of mysql. That's the convention for sql server, I used it because you did it too. You have it here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_add.asp

Comment: Thanks, that would have worked too probably. Like you said I didn't realize its mysql. I fixed it with:
```sql
DELETE FROM posts WHERE postDate < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 DAY)
```